# Change matplotlib Button color when pressed

Tags: python, user-interface, animation, button, matplotlib

I'm running an animation using matplotlib's `FuncAnimation` to display data (live) from a microprocessor. I'm using buttons to send commands to the processor and would like the color of the button to change after being clicked, but I can't find anything in the `matplotlib.widgets.button` documentation (yet) that achieves this.

```
class Command:

    def motor(self, event):
    SERIAL['Serial'].write(' ')
    plt.draw()

write = Command()
bmotor = Button(axmotor, 'Motor', color = '0.85', hovercolor = 'g')
bmotor.on_clicked(write.motor)            #Change Button Color Here
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set `button.color`.

E.g.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import itertools


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
button = Button(ax, 'Click me!')

colors = itertools.cycle(['red', 'green', 'blue'])

def change_color(event):
    button.color = next(colors)
    # If you want the button's color to change as soon as it's clicked, you'll
    # need to set the hovercolor, as well, as the mouse is still over it
    button.hovercolor = button.color
    fig.canvas.draw()

button.on_clicked(change_color)

plt.show()
```

Comment: In this example there is a single button. But what if there are several buttons, and you would like to change the color of the one clicked?

Comment: @KurtPeek - First off, each button is connected to its own callback, so you'll typically connect different callback functions to different buttons when you want different behavior.  (E.g. the case above uses a closure, so could use a more explicit `lambda` or `functools.partial`, etc instead). However, if you need to, you can compare `event.inaxes` to `button.ax`. Each `Button` instance takes up an entire `Axes`, so the axes that the event occurs in will correspond to the button.  There are some caveats there if you have overlapping axes, however (e.g. a button inside another axes).

Answer (score 3):

In current matplotlib version (1.4.2) 'color' and 'hovercolor' are took into account only when mouse '_motion' event has happened, so the button change color not when you press mouse button, but only when you move mouse afterwards.

Nevertheless, you can change button background manually:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button
import itertools

button = Button(plt.axes([0.45, 0.45, 0.2, 0.08]), 'Blink!')


def button_click(event):
    button.ax.set_axis_bgcolor('teal')
    button.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

    # Also you can add timeout to restore previous background:
    plt.pause(0.2)
    button.ax.set_axis_bgcolor(button.color)
    button.ax.figure.canvas.draw()


button.on_clicked(button_click)

plt.show()
```

Comment: use `set_facecolor` instead of `set_axis_bgcolor` for current matplotlib versions

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone do not want to make the Button as a global variable when changing the colour, here is a solution:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def change_color(button):
    button.color = 'red'

def main():
    button = Button(plt.axes([0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.05]), 'Click here')
    button.on_clicked(lambda _: change_color(button))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```